# Android - hide keyboard input for EditText when focus (API >=17)

Tags: android

I have tried with lots of method, but none of it working or probably for API < 17.  Can anyone show me how to hide the keyboard when focus or click on the EditText ?

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.f1entrygroup);
        for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
            View view = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof EditText) {
                view.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
                view.setOnClickListener(entryClickListener);

                ***//HOW TO DISABLE THE KEYBOARD POP UP AT HERE?***

            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: add code, how you try.

Comment: which method you have used to hide the keyboard

Comment: @Louise, are you need an EditText without keyboard?

Comment: **imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);**, 
**

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditTextName.getWindowToken(), 0);

**
, and etc..

Comment: hide keyboard when lost focus ?

Comment: hide keyboard when focus on EditText.

Comment: Do you want to hide keyboard on edittext? Why don't you use textview instead?

If you still want to use editext and hide keyboard set its inout type to null in xml or through code.

your_editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code after setting layout in onCreate() method

```
EditText edtView=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
edtView.setInputType(0);
```

When you touch or focus the SoftInputKeyboard will not popup. Hope it helps

Comment: `
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.f1entrygroup);
        for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
            View view = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof EditText) {
                view.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
                view.setOnClickListener(entryClickListener);
                if (i > 1){
                    ((EditText) view).setInputType(0);
                }
            }
        }
`

Answer (score 0):

You can hide soft keyboard by calling this method

```
public  void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener focusListener = (v, hasFocus) -> {
       if (hasFocus) {
           InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context
                   .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
           inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
       }
};
```